# Issue with slicing R data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which contains a column called "g".The values that "g" can take are 5 different string such as "ab","ac","ad",ae","af".

I want to use just a subset that in column "g" are contained let's say only "ab","ac" as values.

I create a new subset by checking which of the strings in column "g" are "ab " or "ac" and the resulting data matrix seems fine. But when I apply this new dataframe to "lda" or "qda" methods, these methods seem to detect that values such "ad" or "ae" were there and the relevant functions don't work.

What is the problem with my slicing of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and wrap with `droplevels` if the column is `factor` to drop the unused `levels`

```
droplevels(subset(df1, g %in% c('ab', 'ac')))
```